# "ScrollView" like component in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am displaying search results in my app as an unordered list. This works fine when there are like 5 search results, but as soon as I start getting 10-20 results, the list starts growing more and more down the page. I would like to avoid having to scroll down in the entire webpage just to see the contents lower in the list. Is there something like a scroll view where I can define a certain height and then users can scroll inside of the container?

My current code:

```
class SearchResults extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles.wrapperDiv}>
                <div style={styles.resultsLeft}>
                    <ul style = {{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
                        <Result results={this.props.results}/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div style={styles.mapRight}>
                    <GoogleMap/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your question might be more of a styling question, Do you have a screenshot of your example?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try giving the parent container (`wrapperDiv`) a height, say 500px and also set `overflow-y` to be `scroll`:

```
<div styles={{ height: '500px', overflowY: 'scroll' }} style={styles.wrapperDiv}>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Need to add `white-space: nowrap` also I guess

Answer (score 0):

try this for scroll view on reactJs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cantonjs/react-scroll-view